# Sample DevicePolicyManager codes from Android 2.2 work?

Tags: java, android

Im looking for some sample codes to start with thanks, although i can read the api ,this will be a big help for others to help with a simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the API Demo:

```
    // Password quality spinner choices
    // This list must match the list found in 
    // samples/ApiDemos/res/values/arrays.xml
    final static int mPasswordQualityValues[] = new int[] {
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC
    };
```

Ref: [DeviceAdminSample.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html)

Comment: actually i had the demo running and seems that they covered everything well.

Comment: needs to bypass the login for it